# How to remove default vertical Paddings of Text Composable in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose, padding

### There are vertical paddings of Text Composable as you can see below

[image]

To remove vertical paddings of Text, I tried to modify my code, but not working.

```
            Text(
                text = "2",
                fontSize = 100.sp,
==================
Case 1.
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),      ## First thing I tried, but not working.

==================
Case 2.
                style = LocalTextStyle.current.merge(   ## Second, but also not working.
                    TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 100.sp,
                        // lineHeight = 2.5.em,
                        lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                            alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Bottom,
                            trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.LastLineBottom,
                        ),
                    ),
                )

            ) // The end of the Text()
```

Those cases are not working.

I want to remove paddings of that Text Composable, and result in having padding 0.

======Edited======

Also, I test in @Preview function

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewText100sp() {
    Text(
        "100",
        fontSize = 100.sp
    )
}
```

But, still it seems like Text() have vertical paddings like below.

[image]

Comment: did you put your Text in any composable function like Box,Column or Row anything ?

Comment: @JayantKumar yes, the Text() in the row in the column, ie. Column { Row { Text { } } }. is there any effect by?

Comment: May be you provided the padding to column or row because by default it doesn't take any padding.

Comment: thanks! but I tested the Text() in the @Preview function on Surface { Text("100", fontSize = 100.sp) }, it seems like that there are vertical paddings by default. Text() might not have vertical padding VALUE, but still looks like having vertical paddings

Comment: try to remove surface and test it

Comment: i tested in my device , everything seems fine.

Comment: I got my question edited. Please check the edit. I want to completely remove the space around '100'.

Comment: did you try in real device. I think in real device it will work fine.

Comment: it doesn't work . 

Comment: i don't know why it's happening , it should not be.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)` to your text's Modifier

or you can use your custom line height as well, this way -

```
style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall.copy(
    lineHeight = 14.sp,  // Here line height
)
```